# How can we programatically stop flash video in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have embedded a flash based video in my HTML and showing it in a modal popup. When I close the popup, I want to programatically stop the playing video. How can I do this? I want to do this with JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<video controls="controls" loop="loop" poster="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/Keynote_v10_091211_ProResHQ_MIXED_AUDIO_750k.jpg")" width="640" height="360"  onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="" type="video/ogg" />
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/flashfox.swf")" width="640" height="360" style="position:relative;">
                <param name="movie" value="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/flashfox.swf")" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=" />
                    <embed src="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/flashfox.swf")" width="640" height="360" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/Keynote_v10_091211_ProResHQ_MIXED_AUDIO_750k.jpg")&amp;src=@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/Keynote_v10_091211_ProResHQ_MIXED_AUDIO_750k.mp4")"    allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
                <img alt="Keynote_v10_091211_ProResHQ_MIXED_AUDIO_750k" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/videos/Keynote_v10_091211_ProResHQ_MIXED_AUDIO_750k.jpg")" style="position:absolute;left:0;" width="640" height="360" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
            </object>
    </video>
```

Comment: Often the flash video player you a using will expose a javascript API that will give you such control. What player are you using?

Comment: Please post the embed code you used.

Comment: I have updated the question with code. Basically I am using HTML5 video tag which has API like play, stop. But for IE7 i cannot rely on this so was looking for flash based API for IE7

Comment: @ctcherry Updated the question with code

Comment: Since not allow browsers support the HTML5 video tag, it would probably be better to use a video player library that includes a flash based player for fallback